# looping with ng-repeat through div's using cylce 2, jQuery and angularJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-cycle2

So I am trying to use the jQuery plugin cylce2 to fadeIn and fadeOut divs with text-content.

I got it to work with images but I am struggling to realise it with divs.

---

**UPDATE:**

as I tried to work it in a fiddle it somehow worked. http://codepen.io/svenjaPixelmechanics/pen/GZaeEe

When I tried to change the items after a http-request to my local server it stopped working. No text is displayed even though the html-elements are created. I think this is a problem with ng-repeat? And how do I change the sliding effect to be longer or have a different animation using this directive?

---

**Cycle 2 itself recommends to  do it like this:**

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx="fade" 
    data-cycle-timeout="2000"
    data-cycle-slides="> div"
    >
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ...
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Mel eu pertinax ...
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Utinam electram pertinacia ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**But this doesn't work because of angularJS.**

What I've done so far:

### HTML

```
//prints only the text

  <div id="slideshow2" my-slideshow>
    <p class="slide" ng-repeat="news in news">{{news.text}}</p>
  </div>


//works just fine

  <div id="slideshow" my-slideshow>
    <img class="slide" ng-src="{{image}}" ng-repeat="image in images" />
  </div>
```

### MODULE

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.directive('mySlideshow', function () {
    return {
       restrict: 'AC',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var config = angular.extend({
          slides: '.slide'
        }, scope.$eval(attrs.mySlideshow)); 
        setTimeout(function () {
         element.cycle(config);
        }, 0);
      }
    };
});
```

### CONTROLLER

```
.controller('myController', function ($scope){
  $scope.images = [
    'http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg',
    'http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg',
    'http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg',
    'http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg'
  ];
  $scope.news = []; //is filled on init with a $http request
})
```

Comment: could you create a plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit